# How to get all document libraries BUT Form Templates, Style, Customized Reports

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm building a webpart for SharePoint 2010 to get all the document libraries with usefull info for the user. This means, docs that users uploaded, etc. I don't want to show libraries such as Form Templates, Style Library, Customized Reports, etc...

I just want to show only the document libraries with usefull info, as Shared Documents, or any other users create in the future, is that possible?

Currently, my logic looks like this:

```
SPListCollection docLibraryColl = wb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);

Guid docLibFeatId = new Guid("00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101");

foreach (SPList list in docLibraryColl)
{
    if (list.TemplateFeatureId == docLibFeatId && !list.Hidden)
    {
        SPDocumentLibrary doclib = (SPDocumentLibrary)list;
        //rest of the logic here...  
    }
}
```

I've read [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29327916/get-a-list-of-all-document-library-folders.aspx) that `Guid 00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101` will return only libraries with MS Document Library template, but I'm still getting those undesired libraries in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with excluding the libraries you **don't** want in your `if`?

```
...
if (!list.Hidden && list.title != "Style Library" && list.title != "Form Templates")
...
```

You are already selecting the `BaseType` DocumentLibrary, so you will only receive document libraries, unfortunately form templates is a doclib too, so you will always get it in your selection.

Comment: Well I just was trying to avoid that, but well, I think I have no choice.

Comment: I don't know of any other way to "exclude all MS stuff and only include my stuff"... in the end a forms library really IS just a regular document library... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I used this piece of code:

```
 if (docLib.Hidden || !docLib.AllowDeletion || docLib.IsCatalog || docLib.IsSiteAssetsLibrary || docLib.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.WebPageLibrary)
{
   continue;
}
```