# How to get list of all document libraries from sharepoint site programatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, splist

I am using below code which gives me both list & document library; but I am trying to get list of only document libraries.
Please help me how to differentiate list & document library programatically

```
using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite("https://server/site"))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPListCollection oLists = oWeb.Lists;

            foreach (SPList olist in oLists)
            {
                Response.Write(olist.Title+"<br>");

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606533/how-to-get-all-document-libraries-but-form-templates-style-customized-reports)

#### Try this ways :

```
using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite("https://server/site"))
{
  using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
  {
      SPListCollection docLibraryColl = oWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);

      foreach (SPList list in docLibraryColl)
      {
             Response.Write(list.Title+"<br>");
      }
  }
}
```

Hope its helps!!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite("https://server/site"))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPListCollection oLists = oWeb.Lists;

        foreach (SPDocumentLibrary olist in oLists.OfType<SPDocumentLibrary>())
        {
            Response.Write(olist.Title+"<br>");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help..It is working but I can mark only one answer